# XSLT for converting <table> nodes containing only one <tr> tag to just <div> and <span> tags

Tags: html, css, r, xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT and am attempting to use the XSLT package in R. I would like to search through a document, find all  nodes that only contain one row (defined with the  tag), and reduce these tables to only  and  tags without changing the appearance or losing any attributes.

I have listed two examples of some of these tables below. To help move things along, this xpath brings up all the tables which meet this criteria "//table[count(tr) = 1]". Ideally, I would just want it to be one  node and then several  nodes nested inside to accommodate the different fonts/formats. Happy to answer any follow-up questions as well.

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="c721" style="border-collapse:collapse;width:100%"><tbody><tr id="c722">
<td valign="top" id="c723" style="white-space:nowrap;width:7.69%">
            <div id="c724" style="font-family:times new roman;font-size:10pt;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;margin-bottom:0pt;margin-top:6pt;text-transform:none">
              <span id="c725">&nbsp; </span>
</div>
          </td>
          <td valign="top" id="c726" style="white-space:nowrap;width:5.24%">
            <div id="c727" style="font-family:times new roman;font-size:10pt;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;margin-bottom:0pt;margin-top:6pt;text-transform:none">
              <span id="c728" style="font-family:times new roman;font-size:10pt;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none">• </span>
</div>
          </td>
          <td valign="top" id="c729">
            <div id="c730" style="font-family:times new roman;font-size:10pt;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;margin-bottom:0pt;margin-top:6pt;text-transform:none">
              <span id="c731" style="font-family:times new roman;font-style:italic">Glossary term 1</span><span id="c732" style="font-family:times new roman">— Definition 1. </span>
</div>
          </td>
        </tr></tbody></table>

<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="c870" style="border-collapse:collapse;width:100%"><tbody><tr id="c871">
<td valign="top" id="c872" style="white-space:nowrap;width:10.47%">
            <div id="c873" style="font-family:times new roman;font-size:10pt;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;margin-bottom:0pt;margin-top:18pt;text-transform:none">
              <span id="c874" style="font-family:times new roman;font-size:10pt;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;text-transform:none">Glossary term 2 </span>
</div>
          </td>
          <td valign="top" id="c875">
            <div id="c876" style="font-family:times new roman;font-size:10pt;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;margin-bottom:0pt;margin-top:18pt;text-transform:none">
              <span id="c877" style="font-family:times new roman;font-size:10pt;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:bold;text-transform:none">Definition 2 </span>
</div>
          </td>
        </tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Can you show the XSLT code you've tried so far? That would be helpful so we don't have to start from scratch. Also clearly show the desired output for this sample input so that possible solutions can be run and tested.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:template match="*[local-name() = ('table', 'tbody', 'tr', 'td')][count(ancestor-or-self::table//tr) = 1]">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

See Transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nb9PtD4

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:template match="*[self::table or self::tbody or self::tr or self::td][count(ancestor-or-self::table//tr) = 1]">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

See Transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nb9PtD4/1